# How to have a flow picklist include only a subset of the options available?

Tags: visual-workflow

I am working on a Create Opportunity flow. Our team needs to state on the Opportunity which countries are relevant to it. I have a requirement to present the team with a multi choice picklist that will only include the countries which the Account operates in.

So, for example, Company A has a field "countries the company operates in" with USA, Australia and UK selected. We want the create opportunity screen to only show those three countries as potential choices for "countries related to this opportunity".

I can convert the selected Account countries to a text collection, but I can see no way to turn the text collection into a choice set that can be used with picklist or radio buttons. Nor do I see a way to have a selection on the screen that doesn't require a choice set. I also tried to get all picklist value into a choice set, thinking I'd be able to remove those choices that aren't present in the relevant Account record, but I see no way to remove options from the choice set either. So I'm stuck!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: How is the Account-to-Country data stored? How does it get to your flow?

Comment: Both Account and Opportunity have multi picklists. Account has "Countries Account operates in", and Opportunity has "Countries covered by this Opportunity" (the second should always be a subset of the first). This "Create Opportunity" flow I'm working on is launched from the Account screen, so account ID is passed, and we Get the Account record including the operating countries field.

Comment: have a look at UnofficialSf.com Quick Choice: https://unofficialsf.com/quick-choice-improved-picklists-and-radio-buttons-for-flow/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a text collection, I'd use a record choice set with unique pairings of **Company + Country**.

For example, you could create child Accounts for each Company, one per country, then filter the list of countries from Accounts where parent Account = [the company]. (or create a custom object if your Account processes would have trouble with that).

Comment: Thanks, but creating so many new Account records won't be an acceptable solution for us. We have about 20,000 accounts, most of them operating in 5-50 different countries.